# Delegated form submit event not working?

Tags: jquery

I have a form that is added dynamically to a bootstrap remote modal, and want to wire to the submit event so that I can prevent the submit and perform ajax submit instead.  I usually do this with a delegated handler `$('#somePermanentParentElement').on('submit', '#myDynamicallyAddedForm', function()`

Am not quite sure what is going wrong in this case.  The event does not seem to fire, neither the console log message nor the alert appears. I have a fiddle that demonstrates the issue(in Chrome 40.0.2214.115 m 64bit).

https://jsfiddle.net/9A6pf/5/

```
<table id='testcontainer'>
    <tr id=tbl_list></tr>
</table>
<input type=button id=btn_addrow value="OK">

<script type='javascript'>
$(function(){
  $("#btn_addrow").on("click", function () {
      $("#tbl_list").prepend(
          "<tr><form class='frm_add'><td><input type='text' name='date'> </td><td><input type='text' name='note'></td><td><input type='submit' value='add row'></td></form></tr>");

  });

  $("#testcontainer").on("submit", ".frm_add", function (event){
     console.log('test');
     event.preventDefault();
     alert('test');
     /* $.ajax function will go here to save row */
  });

});// doc ready
</script>
```

Comment: It's probably not working due to illegal HTML. A `<tr>` element can only have `<th>` and `<td>` elements. The browser will do its best to render your content but may well put your `<form>` somewhere else - probably outside the table. Try moving the `<form>` inside the `<td>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roamer-1888 is right.

You can check in element inspector that Chrome renders form's content outside itself:

```
<tr id="tbl_list">
    <tr>
        <form class="frm_add">
        </form>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="date"> 
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="note">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="add row">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tr>
```

Comment: Looks like my fiddle was poorly formed and isn't really the same issue I'm having.  With your and Roamer's input, I was able to fix the fiddle,   Will mark as answer since you identified the issue with the fiddle.

Comment: Updated fiddle just to demonstrate works with better formed tags: http://jsfiddle.net/9A6pf/6/

Answer (score 0):

You can  try another option which is :

1: give an id for the form submit button

2: fire the form submit event within the click event of the form submit    button

3: define what to do when the form submit event is fired, the definition must goes inside the submit button click event because the form is submitted once we click  the submit button

So your can can be  something like this :

```
<table id='test'>
    <tr id="tbl_list"></tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="btn_addrow" value="OK">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn_addrow").on("click", function () {
        var text = "<tr>";
            text += "<form class='frm_add' id='testcontainer'>";
            text += "<td><input type='text' name='date'> </td>";
            text += "<td><input type='text' name='note'></td>";
            text += "<td><input type='submit' value='add row' id='submit'></td>";
            text += "</form></tr>";
        $("#tbl_list").prepend(text);

    });


    // 1: id="submit" is added to the form submit button

    // 2: fire the form submit event within the click event of the form submit button

    $('body').delegate('#submit','click',function(event){   
        console.log('submit button is clicked');

        // 3: define the actions to do when the form submit event is fired  
        $('#testcontainer').submit(function(){
            console.log('form submitted');
            return false;
        });

        // below the form submit event is fired 
        $('#testcontainer').submit();
        console.log('form submit event is fired ');

        return false;
       /* $.ajax function will go here to save row */   
    });

});
</script>
```

here is the jsfiddle example : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hamism/kgmurq07/)